# "Find" function with two outputs needed?

Tags: matlab, loops, for-loop, indexing, find

I am trying to use a 'for' loop find the number of values in a randomly generated vector that are 1) greater than 0.5 and output also 2) the number of values greater than 0.8.  This is what I have

```
function bigger1 = bigger(input, max)
for max = 0.5:0.3:0.8;
 index = find(input > max);

end 
  bigger1=length(index);
end
```

For instance, with the input bigger([.1 .2 .3 .4 .5 .6 .7 .8 .9 3 5]) I would like to output "6" and "3"

So far it only gives me the output for one of the 'max' values.

Comment: You need to output two variables, i.e vector with two elements. try this: `function bigger1 = bigger(input); bigger(1)=length(find(input > 0.5)); bigger(2)=length(find(input > 0.8)); end`

Comment: @Adiel it should be `bigger1(1)=...` and `bigger1(2)=...`

Comment: @Dan Of course, you right! my mistake.

Comment: I just figured that out as well, thank you for the help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a couple of things not quite right with what you're doing.

- Don't use `max` as a variable name. It is also the name of a built-in function, and using it as a variable name shadows that function. BAD practice.
- Same for `input`
- You give `max` as an input, while you re-define it as the loop variable. This new definition overwrites the old one, so the `max` function input is useless.
- At each iteration, you re-define what `index` is--the output of the next call to `find`. Therefore, don't be surprised that you have only the outcomes of the *last* iteration.
- Your call to `find` will actually find the indices to all true values, in general. You have to *sum* all these occurrences, not find the index.
- ... I'll stop there for now :)

A better implementation:

```
function out = bigger(in, mx)        
    out = zeros(size(mx));
    for ii = 1:numel(mx)
        out(ii) = sum(in > mx(ii)); end        
end
```

A more "hacky" one eliminates one line of code, while preserving performance:

```
function out = bigger(in, mx)                
    for ii = numel(mx):-1:1
        out(ii) = sum(in > mx(ii)); end        
end
```

The one that will probably teach you the most once you've figured it all out (it's also fastest BTW):

```
out = @(in, mx) reshape( sum(bsxfun(@gt, in(:).', mx(:)), 2), size(mx) );
```

Comment: There's nothing wrong with shadowing a built-in function, if it is not going to be used in the workspace.

Comment: @MattJ: Sure, it'll work. MATLAB is designed that way. It's just bad practice; also MATLAB's code analyzer will warn you about this. Take one quick look at the sheer number of questions here on SO that turn out to be due to a shadowed function, proves that you're just better off avoiding it.

Comment: Code analyzer won't warn you about shadowing a function with a variable name. At least, it doesn't for me, in R2013b. I suspect all the frequent questions arise from people trying to use a name _both_ as a function and a variable in the same workspace, which I agree is bad. But... if you are organized about what you intend to use your names for, it seems a shame not to take advantage of a capability MathWorks deliberately offers you. What about functions like 'gamma' and 'beta' which many people never use? Are they to be avoided as variable names, too?

Comment: @MattJ: You can switch off/on warnings shown by the MATLAB code analyzer in the settings. Anyway, this will quickly turn into a GOTO, global variables, etc.-like discussion, so let's not go much further. Of course you're right: when used appropriately, carefully, in well-organized, properly documented code, etc., there is no problem at all with using GOTO or global variables or shadowed functions. *Fact* is that most programmers do not meet that long list of requirements, and the repercussions when using it incorrectly simply do not outweigh the benefits.

Comment: Rody, leaving aside the discussion of whether it's a good practice, I cannot find any option in the Code Analyzer preferences that lets you even detect when this is happening. What warning message should it produce, so I know what to run a search on?

Comment: @MattJ: Hmm...seems I am mistaken about that; sorry for the confusion.  I remember seeing it in action somewhere...Octave perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're using only one variable in the for loop, you overwrite it in each iteration - so it is natural that you get only one value. I.e., if you want to store both, make a vector 2 by 1.

Comment: I understand why you are saying that it isn't working: i'm losing the output of the loop each time because it overwrites the first iteration. How do I output a 2 by 1 vector from a function?

Answer (score 0):

Adiel has explained how to do it your way in a comment, however this is not really the Matlab way to solve this problem. Here is a neater way to do it:

```
I = rand(50,1);   %// btw input is a bad choice of variable name as it is a built-in matlab function which you are overriding.

bigger(1) = sum(I > 0.5);
bigger(2) = sum(I > 0.8);
```

or to put this in a loop:

```
limits = [0.5, 0.8];
for n = 1:length(limits)
    bigger(n) = sum(I > limits(n));
end
```

Comment: Indeed it's not the "Matlab way". I just tried to answer in the terms of the question, trying to fix the serious wrongs, which Rody mentioned... And, was a bit lazy to write it in a proper way as answer...